# Passing params to EventMethod in Visual C#

Tags: c#, events, parameters

I have these two methods and I have to use them to modify the selected item in a ListBox and after editing it in the same txtBox I use for filling up the ListBox to get it back and replace It with the old one.

```
private void txtBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            List.Items.Add(Label.Content);
            Label.Content = "";
            txtBox.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void ButtonModify_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = List.SelectedIndex;
        object item = List.SelectedItem;

        txtBox.Text = (string)item;

        txtBox_KeyUp(????????);
    }
```

My intuition says I have to call the EventMethod I've use to fill the ListBox, but there are some parameter which I can't remove cause I need them in the txtBody_KeyUp(). So my question is what I have to write as an arguments to work or is there some other way for doing this?

Comment: The presence of `RoutedEventArgs` there makes me think this is either WPF or other XAML-based technology, in which case you should not be writing this horrible winforms-like code-behind type of thing, but instead you should create a proper ViewModel and use DataBinding.

Comment: Why dont u split them into separate method and call them from whichever handler you want?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Below Code.

Text Box PreviewKeyDown Event

```
    private int _tmpIndex = -1;

    private void TextBox_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key != Key.Enter || _tmpIndex == -1) return;
        ListBox1.Items[_tmpIndex] = TextBox1.Text;
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        _tmpIndex = -1;
    }
```

ListBox MouseDoubleClick Event

```
    private void ListBox_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex <= 0) return;
        TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        _tmpIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

Have Fun